# Best practice to retrieve list of friends information. How to detect multiple queries are finished?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have users structure lke this:

```
{ 
  "users": {
    "uniqueID1": {
        "name": "Anon",
        "friends": {
            "uniqueID2": true,
            "uniqueID3": true
        }
    }
    "uniqueID2": { },
    "uniqueID3": { },
  }
}
```

I want to show a user's friends' names. I have to access `$user/friends/` to get list of unique IDs, and iterate the list to get friend's information. But iterating the unique ID is making multiple queries, and I have to always check if all of my queries are finished. According to the doc, it seems multiple queries will not impact the performance too much, but if I want to update my view only when all of the queries are finished, I have to check how many queries are finished.

Is there no way of 'execute a completion block when all queries are finished'?

**Pseudocode**

```
var totalNumOfFriends = 0
var tempArray = NewArray()

ref(/users/uniqueID1/friends).observeEventType{ snapshot

   var uIDList = snapshot.children's keys
   totalNumOfFriends = uIDList .count

   for uID in uIDList {
     var nameRef = ref(/users/uID/name)    i.e. /users/uniqueID3/name

     nameRef.observeSingleEventOfType { snapshot
           var username = snapshot.value
           tempArray.append(username)

           if tempArray.count == totalNumOfFriends {
              // If counts are the same, tempArray has all of my friends' names
              // Now update view using tempArray
           }
     }
  }
}
```

Pseudocode explanation:

1. Get list of unique IDs from `/users/uniqueID1/friends`
2. 'Save' number of unique IDs. (Explained in step 4)
3. For each unique IDs from the list, get user's name by using ref like this `/users/uniquedID2/name`
4. For each name retrieved, add it to temporary array. Once the count of the temporary array equals to the count from step 2, update my view as I have retrieved all the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has no built-in way to signal when a number of queries has finished. But you can easily implement this in your own code. Your approach with a counter that checks how many items have already been loaded is the most common approach for that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are some other ways to solve this problem other than comparing the list count?